# Add pandas Series as new columns to a specific Dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1],'B':[2,3]})

    A   B
0   0   2
1   1   3
```

Then I have a Series generated by some other function using inputs from the first row of the `df` but which has no overlap with the existing `df`

```
s = pd.Series ({'C':4,'D':6})

C    4
D    6
```

Now I want to add `s` to `df.loc[0]` with the keys becoming new columns and the values added only to this first row. The end result for df should look like:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0   2   4   6
1   1   3   NaN NaN
```

How would I do that? Similar questions I've found only seem to look at doing this for one column or just adding the Series as a new row at the end of the DataFrame but not updating an existing row by adding multiple new columns from a Series.

I've tried `df.loc[0,list(['C','D'])] = [4,6]` which was suggested in another answer but that only works if `['C','D']` are already existing columns in the Dataframe. `df.assign(**s)` works but then assigns the Series values to all rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`join`** with transpose:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(s).T)

   A  B    C    D
0  0  2  4.0  6.0
1  1  3  NaN  NaN
```

Or use **`concat`**

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(s).T], axis=1)

   A  B    C    D
0  0  2  4.0  6.0
1  1  3  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: If `df`s index were not the default `df.join(s.to_frame(df.index[0]).T)`

Comment: Thank you! And how would you solve this for `df.loc[n]`? Something like `df.join(pd.DataFrame(s,columns=[n]).T)` ?